# What should I set in postfix's myhostname / mydestination?

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, smtp, email-server

I am using Ubuntu, on a web server need to send out email (via sendgrid), this server never receive any external email, and I've the following hostname settings

```
/etc/hostname = example
/etc/hosts = www.example.com.int example (the fqdn has no entry in DNS server)
```

The web server will be accessed behind a load balancer (which DNS set as www.example.com)

Now, for `main.cf`, which setting is preferred?

```
myhostname = www.example.com.int
mydestination = www.example.com.int, example.com.int, localhost
```

OR

```
myhostname = www.example.com
mydestination = www.example.com, example.com, localhost
```

Answer (score 6):

`$myhostname` is [by default](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#myhostname) the same as the systems FQDN. This should be like `hostname.example.com`. Take a look in the manpages of `hostname` and associates to configure it correctly for your system.
The `$myhostname` variable is used in many other parameters, such as [`smtp_helo_name`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_helo_name), which should be a valid and correct FQDN. Otherwise your mail may be rejected by many servers, or at least marked as spam (rejecting wrong helos is a nice spam reduction technique btw).

As Craig Watson already said, `mydestination` is not that important if no mail is delivered there. (But reading mail to the server admin, like webmaster and postmaster, is highly recommended!)

Last thing: Be sure to have this server included in your SPF entry in DNS.

Comment: So should I set a public FQDN (in DNS server) for my web server instead of using private/internal FQDN? e.g. server1.example.com? And probably set a reverse DNS record from the IP to hostname?

Comment: @Howard, yes! Be sure to have resolvable FQDNs, and a PTR record (preferably with the FQDN as result, but it's more important that it exists). Everything other than this setup is mimicking a spammer :)

Answer (score 3):

`myhostname` should be set to the FQDN of the server.

If your server never receives email, then you can safely set `mydestination` to `localhost` as the `mydestination` directive controls the domains which Postfix will attempt to deliver locally.

See Postfix documentation: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination

Comment: Actually this is not true, your system such as cron job still need to delivery email for example, for `mydestination` as least need to include what you set in `/etc/mailname`, for example